# For loop, running a 1000 times the program, average number of rolls required to get snake eyes in JAVA

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

So I posted my question earlier and thought I was all good, but I messed up and realized I had understood the question completely wrong.
I do not need to calculate the average of snake eyes over 1000 dice rolls, but the average of number of rolls to get a snake eyes, over a 1000 play.
I am a little lost in how to accomplish that.
I tried this:

```
public class RollDiceforloop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int die1, die2, snakeye, rolls, game;
        snakeye = 0;

        die1 = 0;
        die2 = 0;
        rolls = 0;

        for (game = 0; game < 1000; game++) {
            die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
            die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
            if (die1 != 1 && die2 != 1); {
                rolls +=1;
            }
            if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 1) {
                snakeye +=1;
                rolls +=1;
            }
        }
        float average = snakeye / (float) rolls;

        TextIO.putln(""+snakeye+" Snake Eyes over "+game+" games, with an average of "+average+" rolls required to get a Snake Eye.");
    }
}
```

But I am not getting the correct result. I am a bit lost on how to accomplish this. Help please?

Comment: Inside the loop you already have, you need another loop doing the actual rolling.

Comment: Isn't my for loop doing the rolling already?

Comment: From a mathematical standpoint there is no way to calculate when you get the first snakeye. You could calculate the probability with a confidence of let's say 99%, which would equal `1 - (35/36)^x > 0.99` which solves for x = 164.
Meaning after 164 throws you have a 99% chance of getting at least one snakeeyes.

Comment: What I am implying with that is that by doing 1000 rolls you will get vastly differing results for every run. You would need to increase your number of rolls quite a lot to get a result that is near the expected value.

Comment: So, let's say for example you roll 5 times, and get snake-eyes. Then you roll 995 and don't get snake-eyes. Then the average number of rolls to get snake eyes would be 5. Is that the type of algorithm you want?

Comment: @ChrisVieulles Your loop is doing the rolling, but the way I understand the question is "roll two dice until you get a snake eyes; count the number of rolls you needed. Do that 1000 times". So you need a loop for the rolling inside the 1000 times.

Comment: But what I am asked to solve is the average of numbers of rolls to get a snake eye after playing 1000 times.
Like I roll the dice until I get a snake eye 1000 times, and then I add all the numbers of times it took me to get it and divide it by the number of play... no?

Comment: Yes Daniu it's exactly that!

Comment: @ChrisVieulles the question is: Are you supposed to calculate the average number of hits it takes you to get a snake eyes (the first?) in n throws? Then as I said: You need a confidence for that. Or do you need to do an experiment (as you did there basically) and calculate a number with it? This will have vastly differing results each time.

Comment: Like Daniu said, I need to "roll two dice until I get a snake eye, count the number of rolls I needed to get it. Do that 1000 times".
Which is what I am struggling to do right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your logic a bit wrong. You need to do N amount of test(games) and every test has to wait until a snakeeye appears and count the necessary rolls. You could say you need to wait **while** no snakeeye appeared. To calculate the average you need to store the result of every test.

**Example:**

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  int dice1;
  int dice2;
  // The amount of tests
  final int SIZE = 10000000;

  // store all results we got from a single test
  int[] result = new int[SIZE];

  // loop through the tests
  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE;i++) 
  {
    // initialize counter for every test
    int rolls = 0;
    do 
    {
      // roll counter increases
      rolls++;
      dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
      dice2 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
      // check if condition is met.
    }while(dice1 != 1 || dice2 != 1);
    // store the result of the test
    result[i] = rolls;
  }
  // calculate the average amount of rolls necessary
  double avg = Arrays.stream( result ).sum() / (double)SIZE;
  System.out.println( avg );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not learn how to store results yet, so I am trying to find a way to do it without that. 
The only condition I have is using the for loop. 
Another user mentioned De Morgan's law and the fact that die1 != 1 && die2 != 1 is an incorrect statement and will mess up the results. I am trying to look into that.

Comment: @ChrisVieulles As a matter of fact that user was right. And to be honest i didn't notice that mistake by myself until you put it up but yeah this condition as it is right now will break when one dice rolls a 1. Let's say dice1 rolls 1 and dice 2 something else then `dice1 (1) != 1` evaluates to false and `dice2 ( e.g. 5) != 1` evaluates to true. `true && false` == false  which leads to a break from the loop. `dice1 != 1 || dice2 != 1` is the correct statement here.

Comment: @ChrisVieulles Also by 'sotring' the results i mean that you keep track of the results of each test itherwise you cannot evaluate an average amount of rolls necessary.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right it now works!!! I looked a bit more into how you stored the results, and adjusted it to my code... and now with the || instead it works perfectly!!! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @ChrisVieulles You're welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as `accepted` so that future reader find the proper solution to the question more easily.

Comment: Creating that array is pointless since you only care about the sum of all its elements. Instead of storing in an individual roll count array you should increment total rolls. In fact you don’t even need to know the individual roll count at any time.

Comment: @PatrickParker That is correct and I noticed that myselfa few hours ago but didn't bother to change it yet. I just like to keep my data organized and accessible ;) But thanks for putting it straight.

Comment: The advantage of using this approach is that the teacher will see that stream and realize he copied it from stackoverflow. Congrats

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your input. I did indeed not learn anything about stream yet. Though, I don't like to copy without getting it myself. So I did a search for it before even thinking about putting it in my code. While I may not fully grasp the concept yet, I can understand what it does in this particular instance.
I am open to your suggestion. I tried to increase the rolls only but I guess I messed up because it did not work at all. 
Isn't it that I am supposed to keep each result (so a 1000 results) of how many times it took to get the snake eye ( 1 and 1)  and then get the average of it?

Comment: @PatrickParker I had tried a for loop, with a nested if branches, adding up rolls and snake eyes, but it didn't work out.  I am gonna post it as an answer so you can see.

Answer (score 2):

A way to simply calculate the number of throws it took you to get a Snakeeyes would be the following:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (result != 2)
    {
        result = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 2;
        ++count;
    }
}
System.out.println(count / 1000.d);
```

Running should get you a result of round about 36, which is basically the expected value as you have a chance of 1/36 on each throw to get a Snakeeyes, so in theory on the long run you will get one every 36 throws.

However, this is kinda skewed math. Does this tell you that after 37 throws without a Snakeeyes your die are inbalanced? Or that if you get a Snakeeyes after 2 rolls you are cheating somehow?
No, obviously not.

This is where math comes into the equation. Let me say this first, there is no way to calculate the exact number of throws it's going to take you to get a Snakeeyes. What we can do is calculate a probability based on a confidence.
A confidence here is basically saying:

> I want a chance of x% to get a snakeeyes.

`x` is the confidence. With the confidence you can use the simple formula of

`1 - (35 / 36) ^ n > x` and solve this for `n` to get a number of throws that with the given confidence will give you one or more snakeeyes. Note that `35/36` is the chance to not get a snakeyes but anything else.

So let's say we really really want that snakeeyes. We take a confidence of 99.9%.
With the formula this gets us `n = 246`. So we need 246 throws to get a 99.9% chance of at least one snakeeyes.

How about us gambling a bit more. We say that we are fine with just a 50% chance of getting a snakeyes. So with that we get `n = 25`.

Which is actually below our calculated value.

So what am I trying to say with that? You can obviously do an experiment with a big enough number of tries and in the end you will always get to the expected value of the throw (this is actually called the "Law of large numbers"). This however holds no value in determining how many throws you actually need to get a snakeeyes. It's just calculating the expected value. Which is something that doesn't really need an experiment for die.

So the method

`return 36;`

would actually be good enough here.

Comment: the relationship between EV and %chance is interesting. so if we roll the EV number of times— that is 36 times— we will have a roughly 63.729% chance of getting a snake-eyes. I don’t think the asker cares about that relationship though.

Comment: “there is no way to calculate the exact number of throws it's going to take you to get a Snakeeyes.” this sentence is incredibly obvious and pointless. surely the asker and any other readers know this.

Comment: Thanks for your mathematical approach. It is interesting. Unfortunately, this is not really what I am supposed to do. I decided to go with L. Spillner answer, because they helped me solve it in a "programming" way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Now my rolls required doesn't even compute.

```
 public class RollDiceforloop3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int die1, die2, game, rolls;
    rolls = 0;

    for (game = 0; game < 1000; game++)
    {
        die1 = 0;
        die2 = 0;
        while (die1 != 1 || die2 != 1)
        {
            die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
            die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
            rolls +=1;
        }
    }
    double average = rolls / (double) game;
    TextIO.putln("The average number of rools required to get Snake Eyes is "+average+", after running the program 1000 times.");
}
}
```

Comment: @PatrickParker My bad, it does work. Stupid me just had not saved the file. 
Thank you so much for your help! Is the indentation better?

Comment: congrats. it looks much better now too

Comment: @PatrickParker A little extra question please... I have another (similar) program where I used a for loop with a nested do while loop to play the game 5 times, and get 5 times "got the snake eyes after x rolls".
I can see my counter just keep going each game instead of reinitializing after each one. I thought I could use an if statement to say something like if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 1) count = 0 but that in turn, just keep the counter to 0 at all times...

Comment: Is there a way for me to reinitialized my counter after a snake eye without rewriting my whole program?

Comment: @PatrickParker I think I got it, I added count = 0 after my output "snake eye after x rolls" within the for loop (and so discarded the if statement) and I think it works!

Answer (score 0):

If understood your code, I think you may wanna start counting over when achieved the snake eye, and increase the number of rolls otherwise. Also you probably want to increase the counter when only one of the rolls is equal to one. This two things may be polluting your result.

```
if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 1) {
    snakeye ++;
    rolls = 0;
} else {
    rolls ++;
}
```